# IOS app icon names still require @2x?

Tags: ios, retina-display

Do icon names still require @2x and @3x for submission..?

Just about every answer I see still references them, but I just saw a doc that said names can be arbitrary..?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html

Has this changed?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question.

Comment: @Almo, no, but it is about: `software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development` http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Hi Almo, are you sure, I see tons of similar questions on SO. It is development related isn't it..?

Comment: guess what if your app supports iPad you still need to present the `@1x` images.

Comment: I've seen lots of questions get closed because they are asking "Will Apple fail my app because of this?"

Comment: Hi Almo, I asked the question because I found that Apple doc that contradicts the common theory out there. Did you look at the link..?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, using **asset catalogs** instead of adding them with drag and drop to the project bundle.

In the asset catalog, you can very easily create an App Icon:

[image]

Then you can select what devices and iOS version you would like to support and the list of required images will update automatically, telling you what exactly you need:

[image]

[image]

This approach also allows you to keep all images one next to each other and it's very convenient.

---

Edit: In case the it's not using the app icons from the asset catalog, you'll have to select it by selecting your Target->General and changing `App Icon Source and Launch Image Source` :

[image]